# Enable Focus mode programmatically in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

iOS 15 introduces the new [Focus Mode](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/06/ios-15-brings-powerful-new-features-to-stay-connected-focus-explore-and-more/), which reduces distraction by filtering notifications and apps.

I understand that a lot of these types of settings on iOS aren't able to be programmatically changed; but, for sake of clarity, **can Focus Mode be programmatically enabled** without the use of internal linking to settings?

Comment: This was indeed an interesting feature. Since a biking app could search for a focus mode named "Biking" and enable it, when the user starts the GPS tracker.

By enabling and disabling this mode a personal automation (through Siri Shortcuts) could toggle the airplane mode, Bluetooth and so much more...

If there is news on this, I'd be interrested in an update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the API to set the focus mode will not be publicly available (Why should it?). However as iOS 15 is still in Beta, Apple could still add the ability at a later time.